# Computing $\eta_P^2$ from $\eta_G^2$ generalized eta for G*Power

Tags: r, effect-size, statistical-power

I am trying to perform a power calculation using G*Power. I need $\eta_P^2$, but the ez package for R gives me $\eta_G^2$. I understand the reasons for it doing this, but I still need $\eta_P^2$ for a power calculation for a replication. Is there a way that I can calculate $\eta_P^2$ from the ezANOVA output, or convert my $\eta_G^2$ into a $\eta_P^2$?

Comment: I have reshaped the data, put it in SPSS and done the analysis. Looks like the $\eta_P^2$ that SPSS calculates is the same as you get from doing the calculation from the F value. Perhaps this is because I only have two levels in each of my factors?